# Default ModelBinder not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, modelbinders

I have this following structure:

```
public class Dummy
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public InnerDummy Dum { get; set; }
}

public class InnerDummy
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And an `ActionResult` that receives a `Dummy`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Dummy dum)
{
    var dsad = dum;
    //var dwss = idum;

    return RedirectToAction("index");
}
```

On my view I have:

```
@model TestMVC3Razor.Controllers.HomeController.Dummy
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(o => o.Dum)

    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

It is posting

```
Name=xxx
Dum.Name=yyy
```

But when I try to get `dum.Dum.Name` on the `ActionResult` I get `null` instead of `yyy`. Is this a bug or just the way it is? Am I not using it right? Do I need to implement a new binder for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HI~ your view should use   `@Html.EditorFor(o => o.Dum.Name)`

not `@Html.EditorFor(o => o.Dum)`

And postback Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Dummy postback)
{
    var dsad = postback;
    var a = postback.Name;        //get Name of Dummy
    var b = postback.Dum.Name;    //get Name of InnerDummy of Dummy

    return RedirectToAction("index");
}
```

If you have problems about it, please let me know :)

Comment: `dum.Dum.Name` is null and `dum.Name` has `Dum.Name` posted value. I tried different names for the properties but then I get null on both.

Comment: Removing any kind of editor for `Dum.Name` makes the posted value binds correctly to the simple property `Name` of `Dummy`

Comment: Hi~ Tyr my code above,use the different name of postback variable, I think "dum" will make the ModelBinder confuse, so it's work correctly now :)

Comment: By the way, thank you BrunoLM :), this "bug" is interesting and so weird. Cause C# is case sensitive, I think the bug should not happen on this case.

Comment: I think the issue is that POST value names are case-insensitive.

Comment: Nice catch, so the default binder has a little problem... Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pull the `InnerDummy` out from inside the `Dummy` class.

When the default model binder finds the `Dum` property it will try to create an object of type `InnerDummy`, but in its context that doesn't exist.  To reference `InnerDummy` as you have it the model binder would need to create a `Dummy.InnerDummy`, but it has no way of knowing that.

Making `InnerDummy` a direct member of the namespace will fix the problem.

It may also be possible to fix the problem by declaring `Dum` as:

```
public Dummy.InnerDummy Dum { get; set; }
```

I'm not sure about this, though.

Comment: I moved it out but it still doesn't bind